# How to load a JSON file which is located in the same path?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm searching for a way to load a JSON file located in the same folder as the html and js files. The method should work no matter if the files are hosted on a web server or distributed for local offline usage.

I tried fetching the file with XMLHttpRequest but with offline usage this seems to work only with Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you are desperate, you can use `jsonp` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable, cross-browser way to write a webpage that can load files from the user's file system - even if the page is loaded from there.

Embed the JSON in JavaScript scripts instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1) embed the JSON data in the js script.

or

2) use a small PHP file which gets the file content and brings it to the js script by using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Loading file : **data.json** located in the same path as the html file, This might help u...

Path

|- index.html

|- data.json ( Json File )

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Loading a Json using Jquery</title>

    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <a href="data.json" target="_blank">Open JSON file</a><br />
    <input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
    <br />
    <span id="results"></span>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //after button is clicked we download the data
            $('.button').click(function(){

                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {

                        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                        //and pass downloaded data
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //now json variable contains data in json format
                        //let's display a few items
                        $('#results').html('Plugin name: ' + json.name + '<br />Author: ' + json.author.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```